# Import Transactions From CSV:Error: Flat File Source 1 failed the pre-execute phase and returned error code 0xC020200E

Tags: sql, ssis

Getting Access denied error while accessing the file in the network folder  during executing the SSIS package in the SSIS catalog, where the application user & SQL server user have full control on the network folder.

Comment: This error message does not make much sense without context. We need more information about your network topography and server configuration.

Comment: it work after adding the SPN to the network location.